# Online Noise Reduction on Non-Stationary, Broadband Signals

Tags: noise, wavelet, denoising

im capturing ultrasonic waves using an analog MEMS mic and other components on a PCB. My signal is similiar broadband and non-stationary (see [2](https://innovatus-pub.github.io/abstractpublications_archive/2020/paper1_pdf.pdf)) and im trying to remove/reduce environmental noise. I have seen this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52691/real-time-background-noise-reduction-or-removal), but according to my research, the preferred way to do this is using the (dicrete) wavelet transform (DWT). However, the studies i read don't explain HOW they implemented the DWT for signal denoising. Is there a good reference that explains how to do this in python?

Since im developing a system which must work online (e.g. in real-time) at industrial conditions, it is necessary to estimate the noise profile periodically (since machines can be turned on/off at different times). How can i achieve this?

Comment: [Wdenoise](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wdenoise.html) is a matlab function that does this. Check the *algorithms* section. I'm sure there are plenty of python implementations if you search the web. As far as doing this in real-time, check [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/45732/63763).

Comment: Alright, thanks. Do you also have a good example for spectral subtraction? You can post an answer so that i can accept it as solution.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by an “example”. It’s a a little too general of a question. I suggest you look into it a little, and if you have a more specific question on spectral substruction, feel free to ask as a separate question and I’ll be glad to help :)